# Flexbox flex-flow alternative for earlier versions of browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, flexbox

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Kanal Listesi</h2>
    <div class="container">
      <div v-for="(channel,index) in channels" :key="index">
        <div v-if="channel.ChName">
          <img
            :src="'http://uyanik.tv/conf/images/'+channel.Image"
            :class="{selectedIndex:currentIndex === index}"
            :ref="index"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  /*min-width:1200px;
  overflow-x:auto;      */
  justify-content: center;
}
.container::after {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 1 32.7%;
}
div > div > div > div > img{
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

My VueJs app has a container which utilizes from flexbox to shift unfitting boxes to the next rows. The issue is that the app will be used in TVs which uses earlier versions of browsers . Thus, I am not able to use flex-flow property as old versions partially supports flexbox. Right now, items overflows to the outer screen. I must display the items like in the output below:
[image]

But I get this output in the device :

[image]

Comment: use float or inline-block

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` or `inline-block` to get this desired layout, see below example:

```css
div {
  width:100%;
  padding:0 15px;
}

div img {
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gudp8zqL/)

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: It becomes too close to the left side and right side turns out to be too empty. Can't we align them to be same from the both side?